# Route VPN gateway traffic via tun0

Tags: linux, vpn, route

On my Linux box, I got a tun0 dev by ipip like:

```
tun0      Link encap:IPIP Tunnel  HWaddr   
          inet addr:10.10.10.2  P-t-P:10.10.10.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
```

and I running a ipsec vpn server(ipsec-tools) on this box, how can I route all vpn traffic through the dev tun0 on the server, (like Openswan's leftnexthop ).

my vpn client got ip address like 10.9.0.1.

Comment: You have two issues there. First, you need a simple route and then you have to set the policies. You have to configure the policies of ipsec-tools to allow the traffic between the networks. I don't remember the syntax, I haven't used ipsec-tools for a while.

Comment: I tried:

spdadd 0.0.0.0/0 10.10.10.1 any -P out ipsec esp/transport//require;
spdadd 10.10.10.1 0.0.0.0/0  any -P in ipsec esp/transport//require;

but with no luck.

Comment: And what about the routing?

Comment: @diegows ip rule add from 10.9.0.0/24 lookup 3 ; ip route add default via 10.10.10.1 table 3